# Hide line in body_html odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How hide line Your code is ${(object.code)} if code is empty.

```
<field name="body_html">
              <![CDATA[
              <p>Dear ${(object.name)},<br/>

          Your code is ${(object.code)}<br/></p>
        ]]>
      </field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if` for condition.

```xml
<field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[
    <p>Dear ${(object.name)},<br/> 
        % if object.code: 
        Your code is ${(object.code)}<br/> 
        % endif
    </p>
    ]]>
</field>
```